# Title Spacing in Bibliography

Tags: spacing

I have chapter's heading customized, so I want to reduce the spacing of bibliography title without affecting chapter's style. Thank you a lot.
This is the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,onecolumn,openany,12pt]{book}
    \usepackage[spanish]{babel} 
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \usepackage{microtype} 
    \usepackage[garamond]{mathdesign}
    \usepackage{garamondx}%%
    \usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    \usepackage{environ} 
    \usepackage{anysize}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \usepackage{titlesec}%[newparttoc]
    \usepackage{tocloft}
    \usepackage{ragged2e}
    \usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=red,
            citecolor=magenta]{hyperref}
    \usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{-12em}
    \setlength{\cftbeforeloftitleskip}{-12em}
    \setlength{\cftbeforelottitleskip}{-12em}
    \renewcommand\cftsecafterpnum{\vskip 8pt}
    \renewcommand\cftchapafterpnum{\vskip 8pt}
   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    \setlength\fboxrule{0.8pt}
    \definecolor{titlecolour}{rgb}{0,0,0}
    \newlength\labelframewd
    \settowidth{\labelframewd}{~\footnotesize\textsc{capitulo}~}

    \newsavebox\chapterlabelbox%

    \newcommand\chapterlabel{%
    \makebox[1pt]{\fcolorbox{titlecolour}{titlecolour}{%
    \raisebox{13.5ex}[6pt]{\rlap{\hspace{-\fboxsep}\resizebox*     {\dimexpr\labelframewd+2\fboxsep\relax}{!}{\color{titlecolour}\lsstyle\scshape\scriptsize{capitulo}}}}%
    \usebox{\chapterlabelbox}}}
    \hskip-\fboxsep\color{titlecolour}{\raisebox{-15ex}{\fbox{\phantom{\usebox{\chapterlabelbox}}}}}
    }%

    \titleformat{\chapter}[display]{}
    {%
     \sbox{\chapterlabelbox}{\raisebox{-5pt}[12ex][27ex]{\resizebox{\labelframewd}{!}{\hfill\color{white}{\arabic{chapter}}\hfill}}}
    \smash{\chapterlabel}}%
    {6ex}
    {\thispagestyle{empty}{\color{titlecolour}\titlerule[\fboxrule]}\vskip3.0ex\hspace*{3\labelframewd}\fontsize{32}{32}\itshape}%

    \titlespacing{\chapter}{1pt}{1.25\baselineskip}{10\baselineskip}
    \renewcommand*\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \marginsize{4cm}{2cm}{3cm}{3cm}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document} 
...
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliografía}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
 \bibliography{tesis1}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the value of the last argument  in `\titlespacing` and code in `\titleformat` for numberless chapters. Also when you want to set a colour to some know colour like black, it's not particularly useful to set its `rgb` values. It's much simpler to use  the `\colorlet`command from `xcolor`. I took the liberty to remove the horizontal rule above the chapter title for the bibliography:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,onecolumn,openany,12pt]{book}
    \usepackage[spanish]{babel}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \usepackage{microtype}
    \usepackage[garamond]{mathdesign}
    \usepackage{garamondx}%%
    \usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    \usepackage{environ}
    \usepackage{anysize}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \usepackage{titlesec}%[newparttoc]
    \usepackage{tocloft}
    \usepackage{ragged2e}
    \usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=red,
            citecolor=magenta]{hyperref}
    \usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{-12em}
    \setlength{\cftbeforeloftitleskip}{-12em}
    \setlength{\cftbeforelottitleskip}{-12em}
    \renewcommand\cftsecafterpnum{\vskip 8pt}
    \renewcommand\cftchapafterpnum{\vskip 8pt}
   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    \setlength\fboxrule{0.8pt}%
    \colorlet{titlecolour}{black}
    \newlength\labelframewd
    \settowidth{\labelframewd}{~\footnotesize\textsc{capitulo}~}

    \newsavebox\chapterlabelbox%

    \newcommand\chapterlabel{%
    \makebox[1pt]{\fcolorbox{titlecolour}{titlecolour}{%
    \raisebox{13.5ex}[6pt]{\rlap{\hspace{-\fboxsep}\resizebox* {\dimexpr\labelframewd+2\fboxsep\relax}{!}{\color{titlecolour}\lsstyle\scshape\scriptsize{capitulo}}}}%
    \usebox{\chapterlabelbox}}}
    \hskip-\fboxsep\color{titlecolour}{\raisebox{-15ex}{\fbox{\phantom{\usebox{\chapterlabelbox}}}}}
    }%

    \titleformat{\chapter}[display]{}
    {%
     \sbox{\chapterlabelbox}{\raisebox{-5pt}[12ex][27ex]{\resizebox{\labelframewd}{!}{\hfill\color{white}{\arabic{chapter}}\hfill}}}
    \smash{\chapterlabel}}%
    {6ex}
    {\thispagestyle{empty}{\color{titlecolour}\titlerule[\fboxrule]}\vskip3.0ex\hspace*{3\labelframewd}\fontsize{32}{32}\itshape}%

    \titlespacing{\chapter}{1pt}{1.25\baselineskip}{10\baselineskip}
    \renewcommand*\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}}

     \titleformat{name=\chapter, numberless}[block]{}
    {}%
    {0ex}
    {\thispagestyle{empty}\vskip3.0ex\hspace*{3\labelframewd}\fontsize{32}{32}\itshape}%
    \titlespacing{name=\chapter, numberless}{1pt}{1.25\baselineskip}{4\baselineskip}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \marginsize{4cm}{2cm}{3cm}{3cm}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\chapter{A first chapter}
...
\nocite{*}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliografía}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
 \bibliography{tesis1}
\end{document}
```

[image]